# Generating random colors with a bias to one color using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to generate random colors (2,6) using the following code below; however, my end goal is to generate white color (2) more than the rest of the colors. Would appreciate if someone could help. Thank you.

```
GenerateColor = Int(Rnd() * 5) + 2
```

Comment: Use a decision "throw" of the randowmizer to decide for white, e.g. `If ((Int(Rnd()) Mod 3) <> 0) Then color= White` gives 30% chance of white.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - using this example, the chance for White is exactly `0.46`. Which is `0.3+1/6`. This is because in the other cases the white still has 1/6 chance.

Comment: `Int(Rnd() * 5) + 2` gives random between `[2,3,4,5,6,7]`.

Comment: This depends on how often you want each color to appear. You could create an array of color integers and fill the array proportionately. Then select a random number from the size of the array, round it to an integer, and pull that value out of the array.

Comment: Actually `0.47`, not `0.46` :)

Comment: @Viyata `Int(Rnd() * 5) + 2` doesn't this give a random number between 2 and 6? Since Rnd() function returns [0,1). Which, in turn, makes a total of 5 total chances.

Comment: @silentwraith - **no**. Run it about 50 times, you would see the `[2,7]`. Or copy+paste my code, it runs 1 million times, but you should wait about 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a probably a good idea to separate the randomization logic and the logic, which forces a given color to be created more often. E.g., this one works quite ok, giving equal chances to each number:

```
randomColor = CLng(rnd() * 5) + 2
```

However, once you obtain the randomColor, it could be changed based on some percentage, named `priorityPercentage` in the function:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim counter As Long
    Dim randomColor As Long

    With Worksheets(1)
        .Cells.Clear
        For counter = 1 To 1000000
            randomColor = CLng(rnd() * 5) + 2
            .Cells(counter, 1) = GenerateColor(randomColor, 2, (0.4 - 0.4 * 1 / 6))
        Next
        .Cells(1, 2).Formula = "=COUNTIF(A:A,2)"
    End With

End Sub

Public Function GenerateColor(randomColor As Long, _
                    priorityColor As Long, _
                    priorityPercentage As Double) As Long


    If rnd() <= priorityPercentage Then
        GenerateColor = priorityColor
        Exit Function
    End If        
    GenerateColor = CLng(rnd() * 5) + 2

End Function
```

This example runs 1 million times and it writes in `B2` the count of the `2`. The reason to pass `0.4 - 0.4 * 1.6` in the parameter, is to make sure, that the chance for `2` is exactly 40%. We have 1/6 for each of the possible 6 numbers - `[2,3,4,5,6,7]`. Thus, the times when we do not enter in `If rnd() <= priorityPercentage` are also taken into account.